# Correct way to git merge when baseline code changes

Tags: git

We have some legacy code that I'm trying to bring up into a more modern paradigm. Basically, they took code from an upstream team, stripped all of the git information from it, copied the files into an empty repo, and committed it. Then then added their own code on top of it.

Now, I need to move this code to a new baseline. (I have another goal of creating actual branches for this code in clones of the upstream repository, but that's another discussion.)

I created a branch off of the master branch when the original code was added, copied the new baseline over it, and then committed that. I then did a git merge master. Was that the correct way to go about it? I noticed that in one of the files, it seemed like I was missing work that had been done on it from master, and that has me wondering if I'm missing the changes elsewhere, too.

Here's a basic idea of what I tried:

```
A -- B -- [ Baseline code "C" ] -- D -- E -- F ... HEAD
                               \
                                \
                                 -- [ New baseline "Z" ]  <-- Did a git merge on this branch to bring in the changes on master
```

In git log, I see commits A - F, then my baseline "Z", then a merge commit from master.

Comment: You said they originally copied the upstream code to an empty repo; but you've identified `C` ad the "baseline code"... so what are `A` and `B`?

Comment: A bunch of bad ideas... They added the baseline, removed the .repo directory, reverted the baseline. added the baseline again, made a change, and then moved everything to a directory (where the files should have been in the first place).

Comment: Well, it sounds like the ansewr to this question *should* be no, but it's still the most reasonable possibility from git's perspective:  Could the changes that are "missing" have occurred between `A` and `C`?  If so, then `git` will thik that `Z` was intended to undo those changes.
You could confirm or rule out this possibility with `git diff A C`. In any case it's probably "safer" to put `Z` as a child of `A` rather than `C`.

Comment: Other than the above, the procedure you described sounds correct, at least to the level of detail given.

Comment: Thanks! The changes definitely occurred after C. I've verified this by looking at the logs. I'm seeing a bunch of missing includes and some code in one of the .c files when I went to resolve a "both modified" conflict.

I'm worried  that if I put Z as a child of A then the revert/move commits between A-C will get applied. Since they're from two different versions (one much later than the other), I'm not sure exactly what will happen.

Comment: Individual commits are not applied during a merge.  Only the base state and the two ending states matter.  So if `A` is the orignial import, then it is the most reliable "common ancestor" and really is what you should be using.
Seeing the change after `C` is not the same as the change not existing before `C` - especially in an environment where changes were being made, reverted, and potentially re-made.  Again because only start and end states matter, the diff from `A` to `C` is the only thing that can say if using `C` as the parent is "safe enough"...

Comment: ...and while I can't say for sure that tryinig it from `A` will fix the problem, I can't see what you think there is to lose since you know you have doubts about the result from your current procedure.  (Just about anything you do in git is reversible, so it's not like you're going to lose data by trying it.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried going from A, which didn't appear to work (still missing includes and other material in the file I'm zeroing in on). I also tried using rebase -i to squish A - C into A'. Then I branched from A', removed all of the code, added the new baseline and called that Z. On the Z branch, I then tried to "git merge master", but during the merge conflict, again, I don't see the includes and other code in my test file (which is definitely there on master when checking out the HEAD). I'm quite perplexed by this.

Comment: So it looks like there's a merge in there that I'm missing. Another branch was merged onto master as commit 'D', and for some reason, that is not showing up for me when I merge into Z.

Comment: Hmm... could you update the diagram in the question to reflect what you've found?  Maybe with a complete picture a better answer will become clear